# Is there a way to lock a paragraph style onto a text box?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have an .indd file that has text boxes linked to Excel cells. When I update the Excel file, the text box updates but it also loses the paragraph style. Hoping to find a way to "lock" the paragraph style to that specific text box. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "linked?" Data merge?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new object style, and assign a paragraph style to it. Then when the text is updated, the paragraph style should remain the same.